# Скрипт работает только 1 день

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Продолжительность скрипта 1 день как исправить?
Даже если выполнить функцию всё равно не работает.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == 'Report') {
    //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 1) {
      //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 3);
      // if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: когда на 1й колонку пишется инфа то в колонке "D" появляется дата(сегодняшняя)]

Comment: Ваш вопрос в том, почему при создании нового файла там нет скрипта?

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос согласно основным нормам русского языка и общей логики. Если хотите, чтобы вам это решили исходя из текущей ситуации - ищите исполнителя - контакты в профиле.

Comment: Поправил. Я впервые обращаюсь сюда и только учусь пользоваться. Надеюсь  теперь стало конкретнее.

Answer (score 0):

А у вас эта фуункция в `while (true) {onEdit(Какоето значение)}`
? Если да то `var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` должно быть перед `while (true) {onEdit(Какоето значение)}`

*Ответ на комментарий:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
while (true) {
    if (s.getName() == 'Report') {
        //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getColumn() == 1) {
            //checks the column
            var nextCell = r.offset(0, 3);
            // if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
            nextCell.setValue(new Date());
       }
  }
```

Остовлять комп на дни и просто ждать)
На счет google apps script не могу сказать, это ошибка скорее googl'а чем вас

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Здравствуйте, я не использовал while и если не трудно можете весь код написать я бы попробывал поставить, а то я не понимаю где использовать while, не так хорошо знаю js. Спасибо!